# What is the intersection of all maximal abelian subalgebras of a compact simple Lie algebra, containing a given element?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a compact simple real Lie algebra and let $x\in\mathfrak g$.

> What is the intersection of all maximal abelian subalgebras of $\mathfrak g$ which contain $x$?

For instance, in the simplest case of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, with $x\neq 0$, the only maximal torus containing $x$ is the 1-dimensional space spanned by $x$. In Lie algebras of higher rank, there are in general multiple maximal tori containing a given $x$.

Comment: Some examples and heuristics?

Comment: It's the center of the centralizer.

Comment: In $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ for a diagonal matrix $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ these are the diagonal matrices $(d_1,\dots,d_n)$ in $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ such that $a_i=a_j$ implies $d_i=d_j$.

Comment: It depends on the level of regularity of the element. Generally speaking, it is the algebra generated by the lowest dimensional face of  a Weyl chamber, the element sits in.

Comment: In $\mathfrak{so}(n)$, these are if I'm correct, those elements of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ that are proportional to $x$ on each generalized eigenspace of $x$ (i.e. $\mathrm{Ker}(x)$ or $\mathrm{Ker}(x^2+s)$ for $s>0$), except precisely, when $ K_x=\mathrm{Ker}(x)$ is 2-dimensional (happens only when $n$ is even), in which case the element is allowed to be arbitrary on the 2-plane $K_x$. Here "proportional to 0" means "equal to 0".

Comment: @Echo where can one learn more about this?

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the explicit results!

Comment: Humphries book on Lie algebras, for instance. A good survey is in the first chapters of Knapp's book on representation theory of semisimple Lie groups.

Comment: @Echo Great, thanks!